# Django raw query not returning/rendering results on html template

Tags: sql, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Am currently working on an application where am sapposed to access static a database of another app. These two applications are independent but share the same database. 
I am sapposed to perform some raw sql(postgrres to be exact) queries in my views since am bypassing the model class.
But no results are returned on my template
here is view and template code

```
#views code

def receipt(request):
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Data retrieval operation

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM quickpay_client_transactions")
    transactions = cursor.fetchall()

return render(request, 'receipt.html', {"transactions":transactions})


#Templates code snippet

{% for trans in transactions %}
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                {{trans.id}}    
                                                </td>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td>{{trans.amount}}</td>
                                                  <th>{{trans.reference}}</th>
                                                <td>
                                                        <span class="label label-success">Success</span>
                                                </td>
                                                <th>{{trans.t_stamp}}</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first check you are getting any result in

```
transactions = cursor.fetchall()
```

second type of transactions should be list

sample working code with dummy data:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):

    transactions = [{"id":1},{"id":2}]
    return render (request, 'test/index.html', {"transactions":transactions})
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
Test
{% for trans in transactions %}
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                {{trans.id}}
                                                </td>

                                            </tr>
                                            {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

or may be your sql data is not in str:
try this

```
transactions = [to_string(x) for x in cursor.fetchall()]
import datetime
import decimal
def to_string(x):
    a = []
    for y in x:
        if type(y) is datetime.datetime:
            a.append(str(y))
        elif type(y) is decimal.Decimal:
            a.append(str(y))
        elif type(y) is unicode:
            a.append(y.encode("UTF-8", "ignore"))
        elif type(y) is float:
            a.append(str(y))
        else:
            a.append(y)
    return a
```